# Need Syntax to add Ansible meta module to existing Playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I wish to search for a string ("AC245") in all files with extension *.db under /home/examples directory. Below is what i tried.

```
---
- name: "Find the details here "


  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: true
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible find files multiple patterns examples
    find:
      paths: /home/examples
      patterns: "*.db"
      recurse: yes
    register: files_matched


  - name: Search for String in the matched files
    command: grep -i {{ myString }} {{ item.path }}
    register: command_result
    failed_when: command_result.rc == 0
    with_items:
       - "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

run the above find.yml using this command:

```
ansible-playbook find.yml -e "myString=AC245"
```

My requirement is that if the string is found I wish to abort the play immediately using "meta: end_play" marking the playbook as FAILED.

Can you help suggest how can I update my current code to add the end_play feature as soon as the string is found in any *.db file ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to move the task into a separate tasks file and loop over it. That will allow discrete control over each iteration of the task. For example:

**playbook.yml**:

```
---
- name: "Find the details here "
  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: true
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  - name: Ansible find files multiple patterns examples
    find:
      paths: /home/mparkins/bin/playbooks_sandpit/outputs/dir
      patterns: "*.db"
      recurse: yes
    register: files_matched

  - name: Search for String in the matched files
    include_tasks:
      tasks.yml
    with_items:
       - "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

**tasks.yml**:

```
- command: grep -i {{ myString }} {{ item.path }}
  register: command_result
  failed_when: command_result.rc == 0
```

You can add additional tasks in the tasks file if you wish to fail in a different way, for example using the `fail` module or `meta: end_play`

Answer (score 0):

> Q: "The requirement is that if the string is found I wish to abort the play immediately using "meta: end_play" marking the playbook as FAILED."

(ansible 2.7.9)

A: It's not possible.

1) It's not possible to execute `meta: end_play` in a loop on a condition (string is found)

2) It's not possible to execute both `meta: end_play` and `fail/assert` in one play

---

1) It is possible to write a filter_plugin (Python2)

```
$ cat filter_plugins/file_filters.py
import mmap

def file_list_search(list, string):
    for file in list:
        if file_search(file, string):
            break
    return file_search(file, string)

def file_search(file, string):
    f = open(file)
    s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    if s.find(string) != -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters for operating on files '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'file_search' : file_search,
            'file_list_search' : file_list_search
        }
```

and use it in a play. For example

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    myString: "test string"
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: /home/examples
        patterns: "*.db"
      register: files_matched
    - name: End of play when myString found
      meta: end_play
      when: "files_matched.files|
             json_query('[*].path')|
             file_list_search(myString)"
    - debug:
        msg: continue
```

2) It is possible to [set_stats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_stats_module.html#set-stats-set-stats-for-the-current-ansible-run). The play below

```
- name: End of play when myString found
  block:
    - set_stats:
        data:
          FAILED: 1
    - meta: end_play
  when: "files_matched.files|
         json_query('[*].path')|
         file_list_search(myString)"

- debug:
    msg: continue
- set_stats:
    data:
      FAILED: 0
```

gives the output below if the string is found

```
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   


CUSTOM STATS: *******************************************************************************

    RUN: { "FAILED": 1}
```

Allow [show_custom_stats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#show-custom-stats)

```
$ grep stats ansible.cfg
show_custom_stats = True
```